# curious failure of auto-conversion to string in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, printf

This happened (Python 2.7.13 - Linux):

```
import SimpleHTTPServer, SocketServer

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 8080), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
# this fails:
print "%s" % (httpd.socket.getsockname())
# this does not:
print "%s%s" % (httpd.socket.getsockname(), '')
```

Is it considered a bug?

Comment: `(httpd.socket.getsockname())` is not a tuple. `(httpd.socket.getsockname(),)` *is*.

Comment: Technically it is a tuple, but it's a tuple of length 2

Comment: @JaredGoguen: it's the expectation that `(...)` forms a tuple I was trying to address, but yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"..." % ...` string interpolation has *two modes*:

- Either the value on the right-hand-side is a single value.
- Or the value on the right-hand side is a tuple holding multiple values.

The second option means you can never put a single tuple there to be interpolated as a single value; you'd have to wrap that tuple in another tuple first.

`socket.getsockname()` returns a tuple, so can't be interpolated directly, you'd have to wrap it in a tuple first.

Note that the `(...)` parentheses in your first expression only **group** the expression, they do not make something a tuple; you need to use **commas** to make something a tuple:

```
>>> (0)  # not a tuple
0
>>> 0,   # a tuple
(0,)
```

Because you give a 2-element tuple to the string interpolation with just *one* string placeholder, you are told there are more elements in the tuple that haven't been converted:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Add in a comma:

```
print "%s" % (httpd.socket.getsockname(),)
```

or better yet, use `str.format()` formatting and not worry about tuples:

```
print "{}".format(httpd.socket.getsockname())
```